# How to create a chart with chartjs.org with data from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I try to create a website with a bar-chart on it. I like to use [ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/).
There are some good examples, but I don't know how to visualise the data if the data is an array.

```
var myArray = [{
        year: '2016',
        value: 5
    },
    {
        year: '2017',
        value: 9
    },
    {
        year: '2018',
        value: 4
    }
];
```

How do I loop throu myArray to create a bar chart like this one in the example?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['2016', '2017', '2018'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [5, 9, 4],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Thanks for your help!
Best, Marius

Comment: Do you want to plot the property `value` and when it doesn't exist, to plot `wert` ?

Comment: sorry, value is correct. I edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map your array of objects, getting only the value you need.
I did it by 
 `var values = myArray.map((x) => x.value)`
 and then using `values` as the value to the `data` property inside chart options.

For the `labels`, you can use the same logic, but with `x.year`.

Below code represents an example:

```js
var myArray = [{
    year: '2016',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    year: '2017',
    value: 9
  },
  {
    year: '2018',
    value: 4
  }
];

//FILTER THE VALUES
var values = myArray.map((x) => x.value)

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['2016', '2017', '2018'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: values,
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

If, for some reason (browser maybe), you cant use arrow functions, then go with:
`var values = myArray.map(function(x) {return x.value})`

Comment: ohh no! var values = myArray.map((x) => x.value) doesn't work with Internet Explorer 11

Comment: the problem is the arrow function, change it to normal function, insted of `(x) => x.value` use: `function(x){return x.value}`

Comment: I'm sorry, but how should the function look like?

Comment: `var values = myArray.map(function(x) {return x.value})`